# Find latest record from table sql server

Tags: sql-server, date, record

I have a table with modified date and created date. Modified date can be null but created date can never be null. There is another column with student number which is non unique.

Now, i want to find the latest record form the table with a particular student number.

I am using following query:

```
Select Top (1) * from student_data order by modified_date desc, created_date desc
```

but it won't work as modified date can be null.

```
Student Nr    Modified_date             Created_date
12345         NULL                  2013-09-02 11:41:30.967
12345         2013-09-02 11:42:20.663   2013-09-02 11:38:20.663
12345         2013-09-02 11:39:46.103   2013-09-02 11:38:10.660
12345         2013-09-02 11:37:59.480   2013-09-02 11:37:59.480
12345         NULL                  2013-09-02 11:37:44.477
```

It should return me following record:

```
12345         2013-09-02 11:42:20.663   2013-09-02 11:38:20.663
```

Comment: But it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a3fbe/2/0 (-1)

Comment: Do you want the row with latest created date or the latest modified date? Or the latest date from any of these 2 columns?

Comment: What you want to display latest record mean whatever record is being modified last or on latest record depending on created_date?

Comment: @ypercube  latest from any of these columns

Comment: @Tim Schmelter it doesn't work when the latest is from created date

Comment: Why DV this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM
  ( SELECT TOP (1) *
    FROM student_data 
    ORDER BY modified_date DESC
  UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP (1) *
    FROM student_data 
    ORDER BY created_date DESC
  ) t 
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN modified_date > created_date 
           THEN modified_date
           ELSE created_date
  END DESC ;
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9a4b/1) test

Answer (score 0):

I think this sql request will help to you, where :student_id is particular student number.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
 (Select * from student_data AS sd
  WHERE sd.modified_date IS NOT NULL
        AND sd.student_id = :student_id) as TMP
 ORDER BY modified_date desc, created_date desc
```

Comment: What about the case when modified date is null and created date is the latest one?

Answer (score 0):

Please tried with below query

```
Select Top (1) * from student_data order by coalesce(modified_date, created_date) desc
```

Comment: It does work but seems little slow as compared to the ypercube solution, can you provide comparative analysis?